Intersection multiplicity of $y^3-x^2$ and $y-xy+x^2$ at the origin
I am trying to find the multiplicity of intersections at the origin of
$$
f(x,y) = y^3 - x^2 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
g(x,y) = y - xy + x^2.
$$
My idea was to express $f(x,y) = g(x,y) \cdot c(x,y) + r(x)$. In order to do find such polynomial $c$ and $r$, I attempted to do long division of $f$ divided by $g$. However, when doing the division I am not getting an appropriate remainder.
I wish I could show you the process of my long division but I don't know how to display a long division using MathJax. An alternative way would be to take a picture of my notebook and upload the picture, but I don't think that's accepted.
I suspect that the long division is not working because the remainder is not a polynomial, so, is there any other way to find the multiplicity of intersection?
I've been trying to find such multiplicity using the properties of intersection at the origin listed in pages 5–7 from Bix's Conics and Cubes, but I don't see how to make the expression $I_O(f,g)$ simpler in this particular case

Just saying "long division" won't really get you what you need here, since these polynomials are coprime. If you were doing division with respect to a certain leading term, that might work out in your favor, but that's a bit more complicated.
We can solve this with the basic properties from your reference, though:

$I_O(y^3-x^2,y-xy+x^2) = I_O(y^3-x^2,y-xy+y^3)$ via $I_O(f,g)=I_O(f,g+fh)$ where $h=1$ and $f,g$ are as in the problem statement.
As $y-xy+y^3=y(1-x+y^2)$, $I_O(y^3-x^2,y-xy+y^3)=I_O(y^3-x^2,y)+I_O(y^3-x^2,1-x+y^2)$.
As the origin is not in the vanishing locus of $1-x+y^2$, we get $I_O(y^3-x^2,1-x+y^2)=0$, so $I_O(f,g)=I_O(y^3-x^2,y)$.
Applying step 1 again, $I_O(y^3-x^2,y)=I_O(x^2,y)$, and then we may note that $I_O(x^2,y)=2I_O(x,y)=2$.

